# Translucent Bars did not work on android

Tags: android, statusbar

I want to create translucent bar on android.here is my style code ande manifest settings:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

for api level up 21,i have style like:

```
<resources>

<style name="MyAppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="MyAppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then in my manifest i have these settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

then i run it on device with api level 23,i got this:
[image]

the status bar background did not set to colorPrimaryDark which is definitly not white.why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the status bar color you have to set the windowTranslucentStatus flag in your theme. Change this:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

To this:

```
<item name=”android:windowTranslucentStatus”>true</item>
```

Comment: When i set the windowTranslucentStatus,the status bar change to gray which is not what i expected.

Comment: because you have to manually set the color behind status bar to dark in your layout and remove the status bar padding so your app is drawn behind status bar as well OR set the status bar color to colorPrimaryDark (it won't be translucent)